# Strange Text Appearing in Contact Address Area

Tags: wordpress, contacts, database, addresses

My CiviCRM installation is showing weird text around the address area of each contact entry.

[image]

The weird text disappears when I try to edit the address, but when I finish the edits the weird text appears again.

[image]

I have no idea what could be causing this issue. I have the latest version of CiviCRM and Wordpress installed.

Answer (score 2):

I began to import the database in pieces to a new installation to see if I could pinpoint where the issue might be coming up in the database. I found that the problem was with the civicm_setting table. There was a row added for address formatting that had the weird characters in it. I deleted the row and the problem disappeared.

Comment: That's still a little weird since there are actually supposed to be newlines (\n) in there. You can see the setting in the UI at http://your-site.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/address?reset=1, or on the public demo at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/address?reset=1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some hidden characters in your address - this can for example happen during an import?! You could try cutting the text and then paste it without formatting again using CTRL+SHIFT+V.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I haven't gotten the strange characters gone yet. I noticed that the formatting seems to be impacting the spacing. Normally, a line of spacing is created after the street address, but due to the formatting it's not created.